# TypeError [COMMAND_INTERACTION_OPTION_EMPTY]: Required option "message" is of type: _MESSAGE; expected a non-empty value. (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Why does this code throw error?

```js
client.on("interaction", interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isContextMenu()) return;
  const msg = interaction.getMessage("message", true);
});
```

```js
TypeError [COMMAND_INTERACTION_OPTION_EMPTY]: Required option "message" is of type: _MESSAGE; expected a non-empty value.
```

I'm using discord.js v 13 and the djs server couldn't help me.

Please help? thank you

Btw I have no intents because this is going to be application.commands only bot, so I have intents of intents: []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though other sources may outline that you don't need any intents for an interaction-only bot that has only the `application.commands` scope, discord.js requires the `GUILDS` or `1` scope.

Your new client constructor should be:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: 1,
  // ... rest of the client constructor
});
```

Also, the `interaction` event is deprecated. Use `interactionCreate` instead, it's the exact same thing, just a different name.